# Opshub and user migration

Tags: tfs, opshub, azure-devops

I am trying to migrate source control only from a TFS2013 system to VSTS and I have a question about how to manage user migration.

We have been using TFS since it was released and have a >250000 changeset history that we would like to preserve.

We have linked our Azure AD to the VSTS project and I have added in a relevant group that contains most of our current users, but these are not showing up in the user mapping screen presumably as they are not 'proper' users until they have logged on and applied their MSDN license. Is there an easy way of adding around 200 users to the system and applying a license?

Most of the other users that require mapping have long since left the company but it is useful to see which person made which changeset. This class of user will never have an active account on TFS but the current system would force me to remap these users to a current account losing that information. Is there any way of keeping this data?

Comment: Hi, OVSMU will load all available users from the 'Project Collection Valid User' default group. If you make your Azure AD users, member of the said group, the User Mapping in the tool should load up all of them. Also, if the inactive users are not a part of your current AD Users of VSTS, you can default them to a common user. There is no direct alternative for this, I am afraid.